# Fastest way to determine whether or not Instagram account follows certain user?

Tags: selenium, instagram, instagram-api

Currently trying to figure out how to check whether or not very large Instagram accounts (10M+ followers) are following a list of 30-40k users. Scraping all followers doesn't seem to be a very viable solution, as Instagram rate limits at every ~10k requests (so naturally, scraping 50-60M usernames would take very long).

The Instagram app has a search-bar feature that obviously lets one check whether or not an account follows someone; however, I'm not entirely sure how to replicate this functionality on web.

Does anyone know of any ways to achieve this functionality through a Selenium-like bot and / or utilize the Instagram API?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! For anyone who has a similar goal, I accomplished the above with two approaches:

1.) Appium / Selenium automation w/ Android emulator (takes advantage of the Instagram native-only search fucntionality)

2.) *Overkill*: Fiddler and patched Instagram APK (SSL cert-pinning disabled) to find the actual query to see whether a user is following another).